# Switch View in XIB based on orientation

Tags: uiview, view, ios4, landscape

I have two views inside my XIB for each orientation.  They are similar but different so I cannot rely on the autoresizing.  I want to switch these views based on the orientation.  When I use the method didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation then when it rotates from Portrait it will show the landscape view, this is a problem when it is rotating to PortraitUpsideDown.
And if I modify the code for willRotateToInterfaceOrientation then in LandscapeView the PortraitView is hidden from the user but when the user clicks the buttons they do not show gray out to show that they were clicked and it app responds as if the user is clicking the buttons that are in the portrait view.

Am I going about this problem in the right manner?  What do I need to do to fix these errors.  I would prefer to use the method willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Thanks,

CODE:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
... 
    for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
        v.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    }
...
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return YES;
    }

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 
       || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        //Add landscape view
        if(![landscapeView superview]){
            for (UIView *v in landscapeView.subviews) {
                v.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
            }
            //No effect after testing
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.33];
            [self.view addSubview:landscapeView];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }else {
        if([landscapeView superview]){
            [landscapeView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft 
       || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        //Add landscape view
        if(![landscapeView superview]){
            for (UIView *v in landscapeView.subviews) {
                v.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
            }
            //No effect after testing
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.33];
            [self.view addSubview:landscapeView];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }else {
        if([landscapeView superview]){
            [landscapeView removeFromSuperview];
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your View Did Load

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:)
           name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        viewControllerName *newView = [[viewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        newView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];
        [newView release];

    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        viewControllerName *newView = [[viewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        newView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];
        [newView release];

    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        viewControllerName *newView = [[viewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        newView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];
        [newView release];

    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        viewControllerName *newView = [[viewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        newView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];
        [newView release];

    }
}
```

Comment: Should I keep my previous code? Got this error:  `2011-08-17 19:56:13.527 Fraction Calculator Pro[3406:13103] -[Fraction_CalculatorViewController didRotate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6341d50`

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:)
           name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];` Replace your previous code with the updated version of the code

Comment: Didn't really work how I need it to. Was showing the app in portrait always and not showing the landscape view.  I kinda have a very advanced setup.  Requesting Apple's Techies help me out.  Thanks for trying however.